# BigQuery Pagination - Use pageToken or startIndex?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I will fetch approximately 500,000 to 1,000,000 rows in BiqQuery. We will limit it to an offset and max. In this case `pageSize = max` and `startIndex = offset`.

Our data will only be processed once a day and then uploaded to BigQuery.

The documentation recommended using `pageToken` instead of `startIndex`. 
I have done some estimation using `pageToken` and `startIndex` and could not see any difference in time.

I found one answer here at StackOverflow:

> "You should use the page token returned from the original query response or the previous `jobs.getQueryResults()` call to iterate through pages. This is generally more efficient and reliable than using index-based pagination"

But I'm not convinced why I should use `pageToken`, then I need to store the token to use it when going back and forth. Timewise, I could not see any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I'm not convinced why I should use "pageToken"

There are few but important differences between the two

- index-based pagination - Is good when you **know** how many records are returned from your query and doesn't consider the **size** of a record (This is important for client-side application
- page token - Specific page in the result set not requiring any pre-information to access such as the size of the results

So if in your case you know how many results you have and you don't care about the page size you can use index-based other-wise use page token

Comment: I'm not following you. To clarify, the query and the pagination is done on our server-side. 
Our client in this case a browser UI will send a JSON request with an offset and 
max=200, the response will then be for the first 200. The response will also have a total (3500 records).

The client need to keep track on the jobId and the pageToken. For testing I store the pageToken on the server-side.
To get the queryResult I use the pageSize (200) and pageToken to fetch the rows based on page.
I can do the same with index-based pagination.

Comment: BigQuery has an API network size limit which you can't control. This means that even if you ask 100 rows you might get 80 because of the size. The purpose is to make sure you are not downloading a huge amount of data to the client. So if in your use case you data size is small you can ignore this.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, so you are never guaranteed how many rows you get back. I did a test and got 34157 rows back of 100 000. But are you safe like 200 rows or can you never be?  Thanks.

Comment: I did a bit more research and this is the official number from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas), _Maximum response size — 128 MB compressed1_  so it all depends on your data size. Hope you found this answer helpful please consider accepting and voting-up :)